# inputing "up" & "down" keys from the keyboard in monkeyrunne

Tags: monkeyrunner

I am currently testing an application on Android platform using Monkeyrunner & python script.  I want to know if there is any way to input the `up` & `down` keys from the keyboard using the `device.press` command.

I looked at the entire list of key events given in

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html

but couldnt find an option to press the `up-down` keys. 
Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 0):

You could use KEYCODE_DPAD_UP and KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN. It's the same as pressing the up and down arrow keys on the keyboard. I used them in some of my tests.